# Why is there irregular spacing on x axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm displaying a d3 chart with this code:

```js
var svg = d3
    .select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(
        d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
    )
    .range([0, width]);

svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

var y = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain(
        d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.y;
        })
    )
    .range([height, 0]);

svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

svg
    .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr(
        "d",
        d3
        .line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d.x);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.y);
        })
    );
```

Result:

[image]

Why is there a larger space after the Oct 25 label? How do I prevent this?

```js
let points = {
  "prices": [
    [1603546061365, 5682.282498443263],
    [1603546376723, 5684.968260518145],
    [1603546754507, 5684.3964397624495],
    [1603547134564, 5694.944223903203],
    [1603547306978, 5695.369461269177],
    [1603547651102, 5693.132442629076],
    [1603547885395, 5695.930726690588],
    [1603548342262, 5693.802180184249],
    [1603548636505, 5692.5572028902325],
    [1603549288150, 5735.001913346532],
    [1603549466170, 5729.752182406022],
    [1603549916122, 5676.744878676553],
    [1603550186692, 5703.758610524554],
    [1603550442746, 5709.643539627184],
    [1603550670439, 5710.950013156864],
    [1603550984193, 5759.912741361529],
    [1603551342696, 5854.111847242814],
    [1603551606979, 5872.850374712791],
    [1603551896559, 5891.328428877632],
    [1603552245462, 5902.107333283351],
    [1603553291338, 5887.453990891142],
    [1603553680852, 5885.901294518506],
    [1603553955996, 5861.605266416639],
    [1603554229854, 5866.843675356144],
    [1603554685498, 5866.642002136653],
    [1603554964742, 5864.101591224471],
    [1603555234111, 5863.233011345641],
    [1603555839852, 5808.556250434988],
    [1603556067207, 5806.314131790671],
    [1603556362363, 5822.088785966513],
    [1603556720235, 5817.968491658274],
    [1603557046272, 5957.496046081174],
    [1603557305160, 5958.919566450439],
    [1603557696138, 5944.549140328778],
    [1603557859017, 5941.518031624319],
    [1603558197467, 5969.162229992385],
    [1603558576345, 6028.56094735725],
    [1603558753490, 6016.1485632666],
    [1603559116669, 6029.785094918736],
    [1603559462536, 6039.846235097952],
    [1603560057407, 6048.804925202453],
    [1603560221987, 6049.210356188233],
    [1603560686997, 6040.105302239715],
    [1603560917049, 6040.371101473078],
    [1603561251823, 6036.102748365204],
    [1603561586543, 6034.9521061356045],
    [1603561832166, 6030.554627998021],
    [1603561945521, 6040.490915920336],
    [1603562287922, 6041.487004773176],
    [1603562630353, 6040.134500531131],
    [1603562908592, 6036.951544665868],
    [1603563339855, 6030.891388410634],
    [1603563616333, 6034.939055094247],
    [1603563908706, 6022.171083519088],
    [1603564258098, 6023.780549492628],
    [1603564606272, 6019.46979064303],
    [1603564982586, 6016.559661688415],
    [1603565385613, 5980.932640803383],
    [1603565751405, 5976.179972277274],
    [1603566062568, 5973.611618077262],
    [1603566326985, 5995.004416106132],
    [1603566600730, 5998.175979584426],
    [1603566918470, 6004.4384549073475],
    [1603567252041, 6019.081168079008],
    [1603567600735, 6007.681667023986],
    [1603567881333, 5956.2498376312515],
    [1603568120958, 5942.74140090081],
    [1603568469242, 5943.327080607557],
    [1603568673790, 5946.533160987443],
    [1603569013590, 5946.149638602055],
    [1603569161357, 5956.746523098555],
    [1603569681061, 5962.165394114427],
    [1603569965128, 5967.101201850119],
    [1603570270747, 5966.6786096409905],
    [1603570466853, 5963.576094126016],
    [1603570819814, 5967.540680162767],
    [1603571150859, 5954.398040953979],
    [1603571464536, 5958.2351261468],
    [1603571769828, 5954.928339957327],
    [1603572051718, 5942.544258433555],
    [1603572392274, 5941.096427390388],
    [1603572701959, 5922.760688038915],
    [1603572969002, 5881.765951559505],
    [1603573243448, 5881.063154586546],
    [1603573579866, 5878.512663539283],
    [1603573712903, 5884.886944099509],
    [1603574050454, 5887.3963537874815],
    [1603574361572, 5770.241123280416],
    [1603574672225, 5771.610367496096],
    [1603575055906, 5761.478294630396],
    [1603575337702, 5760.639724472842],
    [1603575630203, 5756.574200509254],
    [1603575821540, 5753.082712431987],
    [1603576112160, 5765.582857548744],
    [1603576437651, 5765.106679657817],
    [1603576867667, 5756.193425983812],
    [1603577467718, 5570.925082360598],
    [1603577788023, 5606.276460029177],
    [1603578137637, 5678.945464576187],
    [1603578685163, 5718.798600595409],
    [1603579008089, 5734.634062662832],
    [1603579507677, 5690.3614485247845],
    [1603579670486, 5665.722223822327],
    [1603579976348, 5676.321782480545],
    [1603580266306, 5681.093185357833],
    [1603580630169, 5678.9744232792655],
    [1603580795260, 5643.411798399972],
    [1603581167129, 5649.548057923508],
    [1603581620901, 5648.594757883603],
    [1603581797441, 5643.166735677799],
    [1603582238408, 5646.627007271731],
    [1603582478029, 5650.797879034155],
    [1603582930887, 5655.792953294254],
    [1603583209091, 5186.216600171797],
    [1603583483749, 5172.2476268477085],
    [1603583747290, 5190.64452327681],
    [1603584120533, 5346.89160510641],
    [1603584339662, 5341.630710689571],
    [1603584689813, 5407.229690228169],
    [1603584885429, 5447.0367852343425],
    [1603585230311, 5429.65730639508],
    [1603585618042, 5437.753456100899],
    [1603585763861, 5437.077203972224],
    [1603586153252, 5424.035873615941],
    [1603586408627, 5429.332094790984],
    [1603586684312, 5436.213217693551],
    [1603587035989, 5447.005101708264],
    [1603587362876, 5298.466083944797],
    [1603587634352, 5136.807751869933],
    [1603588336516, 5159.940572677048],
    [1603588691958, 5178.008971277571],
    [1603589013618, 5220.591977699482],
    [1603589467197, 5365.9470643174045],
    [1603590097981, 5229.9017190743425],
    [1603590396477, 5230.793990217984],
    [1603590618499, 5117.589096539744],
    [1603590954440, 5187.942382178123],
    [1603591354249, 5217.227184663773],
    [1603591863936, 5247.7123452673],
    [1603591985933, 5246.829810526767],
    [1603592304122, 5239.215847482106],
    [1603592784333, 5101.527126994881],
    [1603592977122, 4993.0672400536305],
    [1603593338162, 4932.046083125147],
    [1603593671595, 4888.2922014602245],
    [1603594094387, 4814.493966236872],
    [1603594400937, 4912.556018296272],
    [1603594873373, 4925.432197131014],
    [1603595125394, 4926.4623137267945],
    [1603595458294, 4910.096501757009],
    [1603595559081, 4910.0578697730825],
    [1603596066292, 4876.5234460855245],
    [1603596330174, 4854.021823157914],
    [1603596729669, 4868.367987305708],
    [1603596909454, 4908.9292683475405],
    [1603597184829, 4872.614785649899],
    [1603597574618, 4919.380472055094],
    [1603597943524, 4952.241579033543],
    [1603598140852, 4946.926636494331],
    [1603598553387, 4970.179770365939],
    [1603598944196, 5011.363279600457],
    [1603599187056, 5128.005011823183],
    [1603599613032, 5135.0017656123],
    [1603599861847, 5166.163770461731],
    [1603600227988, 5175.217555110156],
    [1603600610894, 5177.085080167532],
    [1603600791661, 5188.497650184485],
    [1603601120501, 5180.551440752915],
    [1603601494868, 5185.486018834082],
    [1603602109559, 5165.140177123904],
    [1603602307237, 5160.573608750335],
    [1603602580745, 5145.196792943237],
    [1603602881019, 5098.9929731000175],
    [1603603177863, 5072.119474068278],
    [1603603559066, 4968.219622976716],
    [1603603856362, 5010.232085388747],
    [1603604133468, 5011.304961236376],
    [1603604452710, 5005.638828603769],
    [1603604736429, 4992.574048982211],
    [1603605087873, 4939.876275213618],
    [1603605262827, 4920.321618332807],
    [1603605628262, 4907.483559533483],
    [1603605781586, 4854.974699766342],
    [1603606227723, 4875.80991807488],
    [1603606395406, 4879.179461917806],
    [1603606714407, 4879.636309922804],
    [1603607046510, 4881.253085770624],
    [1603607425052, 4864.611695747438],
    [1603607763277, 4860.778397320919],
    [1603608082269, 4866.818538543999],
    [1603608351829, 4873.421227407662],
    [1603608639004, 4878.083578361655],
    [1603608965162, 4875.113356208963],
    [1603609274302, 4870.434665620569],
    [1603609809536, 4867.109513075488],
    [1603610348460, 4752.982127549222],
    [1603611007079, 4735.890265394347],
    [1603611412032, 4566.568696647398],
    [1603611865662, 4621.864420221876],
    [1603612148853, 4777.525848495653],
    [1603612565312, 4785.276671380142],
    [1603612918998, 4791.268520211044],
    [1603613261158, 4791.7208172560095],
    [1603613606449, 4790.488133385877],
    [1603613924366, 4808.8427626927605],
    [1603614273096, 4810.504502796033],
    [1603614745304, 4808.157794901196],
    [1603615208352, 4809.013089245778],
    [1603615785569, 4810.001993303235],
    [1603615931858, 4816.966480523035],
    [1603616146348, 4812.561149209058],
    [1603616671048, 4805.844327235994],
    [1603617027508, 4804.05248748379],
    [1603617261496, 4803.348332114384],
    [1603617396948, 4804.1439521532675],
    [1603617835354, 4797.997713716474],
    [1603618140245, 4812.216721066537],
    [1603618455871, 4831.411601800255],
    [1603618759149, 4825.2108253282895],
    [1603619389421, 4825.362086422857],
    [1603619567740, 4824.176006640535],
    [1603619893100, 4580.191888823861],
    [1603620127250, 4604.191985847007],
    [1603620521228, 4597.158717594337],
    [1603620976851, 4550.702553838976],
    [1603621470401, 4481.968569228455],
    [1603621784486, 4479.54096898209],
    [1603622073242, 4482.157710915917],
    [1603622342429, 4466.845861901261],
    [1603622678222, 4527.422489663854],
    [1603623005974, 4527.31609278099],
    [1603623439894, 4560.099254664011],
    [1603623815352, 4580.252044587726],
    [1603624045724, 4571.735446514994],
    [1603624335685, 4598.939534668465],
    [1603624694091, 4591.691647169101],
    [1603625050484, 4569.767631869415],
    [1603625390957, 4577.585269004727],
    [1603625682361, 4573.488082048553],
    [1603625950786, 4598.593478015491],
    [1603626250525, 4619.249893591276],
    [1603626613704, 4621.9843177897565],
    [1603626964550, 4623.241790115797],
    [1603627319824, 4627.736523235109],
    [1603627708802, 4626.697794111737],
    [1603627998170, 4632.61179397423],
    [1603628359456, 4637.348018923737],
    [1603628837011, 4648.634961228945],
    [1603629253765, 4647.926481911748],
    [1603629553107, 4646.466345939407],
    [1603629901541, 4679.789994572156],
    [1603630181412, 4682.604837695135],
    [1603630385009, 4683.2005606225885],
    [1603630779588, 4685.781206466239],
    [1603631054216, 4680.188576048794],
    [1603631318458, 4682.85530526703],
    [1603631628518, 4680.904946933562],
    [1603631839691, 4680.967225005357],
    [1603632041000, 4685.997974619586]
  ]
};


var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60,
  },
  width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var data = points["prices"].map((item) => ({
  x: item[0],
  y: item[1]
}));

var svg = d3
  .select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain(
    d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
  )
  .range([0, width]);

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

var y = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain(
    d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
  )
  .range([height, 0]);

svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

svg
  .append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr(
    "d",
    d3
    .line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.y);
    })
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Can you share your raw/dummy data and also if possible reproduce this in a codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm getting the data from this url: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/ethereum/contract/0x62359ed7505efc61ff1d56fef82158ccaffa23d7/market_chart/?vs_currency=USD&days=1

Comment: Added a JsFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with many time related anomalies, it's because of Daylight Savings Time. Last night at 3AM, the clock was put back one hour, so the gap between the hours is not 180, but 240 minutes. Your time values are in milliseconds since epoch, in UTC, which doesn't have a DST. But the axes are drawn not using UTC, but your local timezone.

Consider the following snippet, which places the ticks every 3 hours, [according to UTC](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#timeHour):

```js
let points = {
  "prices": [
    [1603546061365, 5682.282498443263],
    [1603546376723, 5684.968260518145],
    [1603546754507, 5684.3964397624495],
    [1603547134564, 5694.944223903203],
    [1603547306978, 5695.369461269177],
    [1603547651102, 5693.132442629076],
    [1603547885395, 5695.930726690588],
    [1603548342262, 5693.802180184249],
    [1603548636505, 5692.5572028902325],
    [1603549288150, 5735.001913346532],
    [1603549466170, 5729.752182406022],
    [1603549916122, 5676.744878676553],
    [1603550186692, 5703.758610524554],
    [1603550442746, 5709.643539627184],
    [1603550670439, 5710.950013156864],
    [1603550984193, 5759.912741361529],
    [1603551342696, 5854.111847242814],
    [1603551606979, 5872.850374712791],
    [1603551896559, 5891.328428877632],
    [1603552245462, 5902.107333283351],
    [1603553291338, 5887.453990891142],
    [1603553680852, 5885.901294518506],
    [1603553955996, 5861.605266416639],
    [1603554229854, 5866.843675356144],
    [1603554685498, 5866.642002136653],
    [1603554964742, 5864.101591224471],
    [1603555234111, 5863.233011345641],
    [1603555839852, 5808.556250434988],
    [1603556067207, 5806.314131790671],
    [1603556362363, 5822.088785966513],
    [1603556720235, 5817.968491658274],
    [1603557046272, 5957.496046081174],
    [1603557305160, 5958.919566450439],
    [1603557696138, 5944.549140328778],
    [1603557859017, 5941.518031624319],
    [1603558197467, 5969.162229992385],
    [1603558576345, 6028.56094735725],
    [1603558753490, 6016.1485632666],
    [1603559116669, 6029.785094918736],
    [1603559462536, 6039.846235097952],
    [1603560057407, 6048.804925202453],
    [1603560221987, 6049.210356188233],
    [1603560686997, 6040.105302239715],
    [1603560917049, 6040.371101473078],
    [1603561251823, 6036.102748365204],
    [1603561586543, 6034.9521061356045],
    [1603561832166, 6030.554627998021],
    [1603561945521, 6040.490915920336],
    [1603562287922, 6041.487004773176],
    [1603562630353, 6040.134500531131],
    [1603562908592, 6036.951544665868],
    [1603563339855, 6030.891388410634],
    [1603563616333, 6034.939055094247],
    [1603563908706, 6022.171083519088],
    [1603564258098, 6023.780549492628],
    [1603564606272, 6019.46979064303],
    [1603564982586, 6016.559661688415],
    [1603565385613, 5980.932640803383],
    [1603565751405, 5976.179972277274],
    [1603566062568, 5973.611618077262],
    [1603566326985, 5995.004416106132],
    [1603566600730, 5998.175979584426],
    [1603566918470, 6004.4384549073475],
    [1603567252041, 6019.081168079008],
    [1603567600735, 6007.681667023986],
    [1603567881333, 5956.2498376312515],
    [1603568120958, 5942.74140090081],
    [1603568469242, 5943.327080607557],
    [1603568673790, 5946.533160987443],
    [1603569013590, 5946.149638602055],
    [1603569161357, 5956.746523098555],
    [1603569681061, 5962.165394114427],
    [1603569965128, 5967.101201850119],
    [1603570270747, 5966.6786096409905],
    [1603570466853, 5963.576094126016],
    [1603570819814, 5967.540680162767],
    [1603571150859, 5954.398040953979],
    [1603571464536, 5958.2351261468],
    [1603571769828, 5954.928339957327],
    [1603572051718, 5942.544258433555],
    [1603572392274, 5941.096427390388],
    [1603572701959, 5922.760688038915],
    [1603572969002, 5881.765951559505],
    [1603573243448, 5881.063154586546],
    [1603573579866, 5878.512663539283],
    [1603573712903, 5884.886944099509],
    [1603574050454, 5887.3963537874815],
    [1603574361572, 5770.241123280416],
    [1603574672225, 5771.610367496096],
    [1603575055906, 5761.478294630396],
    [1603575337702, 5760.639724472842],
    [1603575630203, 5756.574200509254],
    [1603575821540, 5753.082712431987],
    [1603576112160, 5765.582857548744],
    [1603576437651, 5765.106679657817],
    [1603576867667, 5756.193425983812],
    [1603577467718, 5570.925082360598],
    [1603577788023, 5606.276460029177],
    [1603578137637, 5678.945464576187],
    [1603578685163, 5718.798600595409],
    [1603579008089, 5734.634062662832],
    [1603579507677, 5690.3614485247845],
    [1603579670486, 5665.722223822327],
    [1603579976348, 5676.321782480545],
    [1603580266306, 5681.093185357833],
    [1603580630169, 5678.9744232792655],
    [1603580795260, 5643.411798399972],
    [1603581167129, 5649.548057923508],
    [1603581620901, 5648.594757883603],
    [1603581797441, 5643.166735677799],
    [1603582238408, 5646.627007271731],
    [1603582478029, 5650.797879034155],
    [1603582930887, 5655.792953294254],
    [1603583209091, 5186.216600171797],
    [1603583483749, 5172.2476268477085],
    [1603583747290, 5190.64452327681],
    [1603584120533, 5346.89160510641],
    [1603584339662, 5341.630710689571],
    [1603584689813, 5407.229690228169],
    [1603584885429, 5447.0367852343425],
    [1603585230311, 5429.65730639508],
    [1603585618042, 5437.753456100899],
    [1603585763861, 5437.077203972224],
    [1603586153252, 5424.035873615941],
    [1603586408627, 5429.332094790984],
    [1603586684312, 5436.213217693551],
    [1603587035989, 5447.005101708264],
    [1603587362876, 5298.466083944797],
    [1603587634352, 5136.807751869933],
    [1603588336516, 5159.940572677048],
    [1603588691958, 5178.008971277571],
    [1603589013618, 5220.591977699482],
    [1603589467197, 5365.9470643174045],
    [1603590097981, 5229.9017190743425],
    [1603590396477, 5230.793990217984],
    [1603590618499, 5117.589096539744],
    [1603590954440, 5187.942382178123],
    [1603591354249, 5217.227184663773],
    [1603591863936, 5247.7123452673],
    [1603591985933, 5246.829810526767],
    [1603592304122, 5239.215847482106],
    [1603592784333, 5101.527126994881],
    [1603592977122, 4993.0672400536305],
    [1603593338162, 4932.046083125147],
    [1603593671595, 4888.2922014602245],
    [1603594094387, 4814.493966236872],
    [1603594400937, 4912.556018296272],
    [1603594873373, 4925.432197131014],
    [1603595125394, 4926.4623137267945],
    [1603595458294, 4910.096501757009],
    [1603595559081, 4910.0578697730825],
    [1603596066292, 4876.5234460855245],
    [1603596330174, 4854.021823157914],
    [1603596729669, 4868.367987305708],
    [1603596909454, 4908.9292683475405],
    [1603597184829, 4872.614785649899],
    [1603597574618, 4919.380472055094],
    [1603597943524, 4952.241579033543],
    [1603598140852, 4946.926636494331],
    [1603598553387, 4970.179770365939],
    [1603598944196, 5011.363279600457],
    [1603599187056, 5128.005011823183],
    [1603599613032, 5135.0017656123],
    [1603599861847, 5166.163770461731],
    [1603600227988, 5175.217555110156],
    [1603600610894, 5177.085080167532],
    [1603600791661, 5188.497650184485],
    [1603601120501, 5180.551440752915],
    [1603601494868, 5185.486018834082],
    [1603602109559, 5165.140177123904],
    [1603602307237, 5160.573608750335],
    [1603602580745, 5145.196792943237],
    [1603602881019, 5098.9929731000175],
    [1603603177863, 5072.119474068278],
    [1603603559066, 4968.219622976716],
    [1603603856362, 5010.232085388747],
    [1603604133468, 5011.304961236376],
    [1603604452710, 5005.638828603769],
    [1603604736429, 4992.574048982211],
    [1603605087873, 4939.876275213618],
    [1603605262827, 4920.321618332807],
    [1603605628262, 4907.483559533483],
    [1603605781586, 4854.974699766342],
    [1603606227723, 4875.80991807488],
    [1603606395406, 4879.179461917806],
    [1603606714407, 4879.636309922804],
    [1603607046510, 4881.253085770624],
    [1603607425052, 4864.611695747438],
    [1603607763277, 4860.778397320919],
    [1603608082269, 4866.818538543999],
    [1603608351829, 4873.421227407662],
    [1603608639004, 4878.083578361655],
    [1603608965162, 4875.113356208963],
    [1603609274302, 4870.434665620569],
    [1603609809536, 4867.109513075488],
    [1603610348460, 4752.982127549222],
    [1603611007079, 4735.890265394347],
    [1603611412032, 4566.568696647398],
    [1603611865662, 4621.864420221876],
    [1603612148853, 4777.525848495653],
    [1603612565312, 4785.276671380142],
    [1603612918998, 4791.268520211044],
    [1603613261158, 4791.7208172560095],
    [1603613606449, 4790.488133385877],
    [1603613924366, 4808.8427626927605],
    [1603614273096, 4810.504502796033],
    [1603614745304, 4808.157794901196],
    [1603615208352, 4809.013089245778],
    [1603615785569, 4810.001993303235],
    [1603615931858, 4816.966480523035],
    [1603616146348, 4812.561149209058],
    [1603616671048, 4805.844327235994],
    [1603617027508, 4804.05248748379],
    [1603617261496, 4803.348332114384],
    [1603617396948, 4804.1439521532675],
    [1603617835354, 4797.997713716474],
    [1603618140245, 4812.216721066537],
    [1603618455871, 4831.411601800255],
    [1603618759149, 4825.2108253282895],
    [1603619389421, 4825.362086422857],
    [1603619567740, 4824.176006640535],
    [1603619893100, 4580.191888823861],
    [1603620127250, 4604.191985847007],
    [1603620521228, 4597.158717594337],
    [1603620976851, 4550.702553838976],
    [1603621470401, 4481.968569228455],
    [1603621784486, 4479.54096898209],
    [1603622073242, 4482.157710915917],
    [1603622342429, 4466.845861901261],
    [1603622678222, 4527.422489663854],
    [1603623005974, 4527.31609278099],
    [1603623439894, 4560.099254664011],
    [1603623815352, 4580.252044587726],
    [1603624045724, 4571.735446514994],
    [1603624335685, 4598.939534668465],
    [1603624694091, 4591.691647169101],
    [1603625050484, 4569.767631869415],
    [1603625390957, 4577.585269004727],
    [1603625682361, 4573.488082048553],
    [1603625950786, 4598.593478015491],
    [1603626250525, 4619.249893591276],
    [1603626613704, 4621.9843177897565],
    [1603626964550, 4623.241790115797],
    [1603627319824, 4627.736523235109],
    [1603627708802, 4626.697794111737],
    [1603627998170, 4632.61179397423],
    [1603628359456, 4637.348018923737],
    [1603628837011, 4648.634961228945],
    [1603629253765, 4647.926481911748],
    [1603629553107, 4646.466345939407],
    [1603629901541, 4679.789994572156],
    [1603630181412, 4682.604837695135],
    [1603630385009, 4683.2005606225885],
    [1603630779588, 4685.781206466239],
    [1603631054216, 4680.188576048794],
    [1603631318458, 4682.85530526703],
    [1603631628518, 4680.904946933562],
    [1603631839691, 4680.967225005357],
    [1603632041000, 4685.997974619586]
  ]
};


var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60,
  },
  width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var data = points["prices"].map((item) => ({
  x: item[0],
  y: item[1]
}));

var svg = d3
  .select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3
  .scaleTime()
  .domain(
    d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
  )
  .range([0, width]);

svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(d3.utcHour.every(3)));

var y = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain(
    d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
  )
  .range([height, 0]);

svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));

svg
  .append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr(
    "d",
    d3
    .line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.y);
    })
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```